# git-clone a bare repo with nodegit

Tags: node.js, git, git-branch, git-fetch, nodegit

## Hi,

I am cloning a worktree as a bare repo in `nodegit`

```
Git.Clone('/work/localrepo', '/git/newbare', {bare: 1})
```

This creates a bare repo just like

```
# in /git/newbare
> git clone --bare /work/localrepo
```

Note: `newbare` has refs to all `localrepo` branches in `/git/newbare/refs/remote/origin`,
but only `localrepo's` active branch is cloned in the `newbare's` local refs

That means that if `localrepo` was on master when it was cloned, then `newbare` is only tracking master

Now in `git` I can track all branches on `origin` with

```
#in bare

> git fetch origin '+refs/*;refs/*'

>>> /git/newbare
    From /work/localrepo
      * [new branch]      feature     -> feature
```

Look at [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) if you want more info on the fetch here.

## Problem

I can't figure out how to setup tracking branches in a bare directory, for all branches on `remote/origin` with `nodegit`

Answer (score 1):

## Got it

I wrote this and solved my problem

```
module.exports = {
    async trackRemoteBranch(repo, remote_name, branch_name) {

        let remote_path = path.join(remote_name, branch_name)

        let branch_commit = await repo.getBranchCommit(remote_path)
        let branch_ref = await repo.createBranch(branch_name, branch_commit)
        await Branch.setUpstream(branch_ref, remote_path)
        return true

    },
    /**
     * refs/remotes/origin/master =>
     * {
     *  remote_name: origin,
     *  branch_name: master,
     * }
     * very rough solution
     */
    async cleaveRef(remote_ref) {
        let parts = remote_ref.split('/')
        let [remote_name, branch_name] = parts.slice(parts.length - 2)
        return {
            remote_name,
            branch_name
        }
    },
    async getRemoteReferences(repo) {
        let refs = await repo.getReferences()
        let remote_refs = refs
            .filter((ref) => ref.isRemote())
            .map(ref => ref.name())
        return remote_refs
    },
    async trackAll(repo) {
        (await this.getRemoteReferences(repo))
            .map(ref => this.cleaveRef(ref))
            .forEach(async ({remote_name, branch_name}) => {
                try {
                    await this.trackRemoteBranch(config, remote_name, branch_name)
                } catch (err) {}
            })
        return true
    }
}
```

If anyone finds this interesting, I can do my best to explain. For now, here ya go. Have a good one guys!